# How to add project instead of jar in vscode?

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, jar

I have a gradle wrapper based java project A in which I am using jar of another project B.

I want to debug a code of jar project B while running A.

This was easy in Eclipse as we just need to add project B to current project A in workspace and adjust the import order.

Is there any way to achieve same in VSCode ?

Answer (score 1):

Make project and Jar be stored in the same one folder then open the folder in VS Code. The folder can be a new workspace.

Reference: [Workspace in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces)